# Do math in MySQL from SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL query like this

```sql
SELECT `transaction`.id,
CONCAT(contact.`name`, " ", contact.last_name) as fullName,
(SELECT SUM(total) FROM transaction_product WHERE transaction_product.ref_transaction = `transaction`.id) as subtotal,
    (SELECT SUM(transaction_payment.idr_cash + transaction_payment.idr_bni + transaction_payment.idr_ame_exp + transaction_payment.idr_cc_niaga) FROM transaction_payment WHERE transaction_payment.`transaction` = `transaction`.id ) AS payment,
    (subtotal - payment) as balance
FROM `transaction`
LEFT JOIN contact
    ON contact.id = `transaction`.contact_id
WHERE reservation_status = 3
    AND `transaction`.id = 6345
```

As you see, I want to get the balance which that math come in SELECT. `(subtotal - payment) as balance`
how should I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use your initial result as a subquery, hence:

```
SELECT          id,
                fullName,
                subtotal,
                payment,
                (subtotal-payment) as balance

FROM                     
(
  SELECT `transaction`.id, 
      CONCAT(contact.`name`, " ", contact.last_name) as fullName, 
      (SELECT SUM(total) FROM transaction_product WHERE transaction_product.ref_transaction = `transaction`.id) as subtotal, 
      (SELECT SUM(transaction_payment.idr_cash + transaction_payment.idr_bni + transaction_payment.idr_ame_exp + transaction_payment.idr_cc_niaga) FROM transaction_payment WHERE transaction_payment.`transaction` = `transaction`.id ) AS payment
  FROM `transaction` 
  LEFT JOIN contact 
      ON contact.id = `transaction`.contact_id 
  WHERE reservation_status = 3 
      AND `transaction`.id = 6345
  )
```

Comment: Nice!, full code answer. Tried your code, after the end of from the SQL as me to add the aliases. Thank you :)

Answer (score 11):

You can't use aliases that are defined in the SELECT clause to calculate other columns that are also in the same SELECT clause. You have at least three options:

1. Repeat the subquery every time you need to use it. This is has the disavantage that you will need to repeat a lot of code. Since your subqueries are long and complex, this is an undesirable option.
2. Use a subquery and an outer query.

   ```
   SELECT
       *,
       (subtotal - payment) AS balance
   FROM
   (
        SELECT 
            ...,
            (...) AS subtotal,
            (...) AS payment
        FROM ... 
   ) T1
   ```
3. Use a JOIN instead of subselects. This is slightly more complex for your situation, but it will be better for performance if you ever need to fetch more than one row.

Comment: @GusDeCooL: Full code is fine if you just want to copy + paste, but I think it's much better to demonstrate the principle and provide a skeleton that clearly shows the concept rather than just posting a wall of code. Even if you don't find it useful, other people visiting the site will.

Comment: For newbie like me, adding full code help me to understand the principle you wrote.