# how to subtract result between two columns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using query to search trips for departure and destinations, and check if free seats are available, I also want to output number of free seats available, but can't figure how to subtract result from `max_seats` and `taken_seats` into something like `free_seats`

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM trips 
 WHERE departure = :departure 
   AND destination = :destination 
   AND taken_seats < max_seats
";
```

Comment: What are the statements for figuring out `taken_seats` and `max_seats`?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779303/do-math-in-mysql-from-select, second answer might have something you are looking for

Comment: You can't figure out how to subtract max_seats from taken_seats?

Comment: `select *, max_seats-taken_seats as free_seats ...`???

Comment: 'max_seats - taken_seats = free_seats' just an illustration

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol ill try it now

Comment: I know they say there's no such thing as a dumb question but I guess every rule has its exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
$sql = "
 SELECT *,(max_seats - taken_seats ) as free_seats
 FROM trips 
 WHERE departure = :departure 
 AND destination = :destination 
 AND taken_seats < max_seats
 ";
```

mysql support substract between columns on query.